# Set action after delay Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Im trying to refresh my Fragment with task after a period of time.

I've tried this

```
val executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate( {
            dailyRefresh()
        }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

This is placed within onViewCreated function. the dailyRefresh function

```
private fun dailyRefresh(){
        reloadFragment()
        createChannel()
        addNotification()
    }
```

I wanted to test if the fragment updates and sends noti after 10 seconds. Unfortunatelly, if i try to do anything in the emulator (my app has bottom nav), when i tap it, the app crashes. is it a placement mistake or did i do something wrong? The functions within dailyRefresh works fine, since when i create button and make the button do these functions, everything works fine.

Comment: You're probably calling some function that's only allowed to be called on the main thread. It would help if you shared the stack trace.

Comment: If you're creating an executor, that's a new thread you're calling `dailyRefresh()` on, and like Tenfour04 says if that interacts with anything that has to be called on the main thread (which it probably does since you're updating the UI?) then it will crash. It would be a lot easier to just create a coroutine that loops on this task, or use `postDelayed` (you can call it on a `View`) to post a `Runnable` to the message queue, that does the update and posts itself again with the same delay. Both keep things on the main thread and avoid these kinds of troubles!

Comment: @Tenfour04 im kinda new to kotlin, where can i find it?

Comment: @cactustictacs okay, thx. Two things: can the postDelayed function for long period of time? i wanted to refresh it after 24 hours (the 10 seconds are just for testing), second, does the timer run even when the app is down, or is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: Every time you have a crash while running an app with your device connected to the computer, there is a stack trace that appears in the log at the bottom of the IDE window. You should always copy-paste that stack trace into any question you post on StackOverflow if you can't figure it out yourself. The stack trace tells you exactly which line of code caused the crash and why.

Comment: You can't use postDelayed or coroutines or executors or anything like that do to something after a long period of time. None of them will work if the app becomes suspended (other apps opening, the user receives a call, the screen is turned off, etc). You need to read up on WorkManager and Services.

Comment: Yeah, what I suggested is purely for while the app is running / while the UI is displayed - when your app is in the background, the system will eventually kill its process. Like Tenfour04 says, use WorkManager (or an alarm) to schedule events, or a foreground Service if it needs to run continuously when your app is closed/in the background (which isn't the case if this just needs to trigger every 24 hours).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, both of you. I was wondering, my initial plan was that it would refresh at specific time (for example every day at 8 am), do you know how that could be possible?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Comment: ive got one more question for the WorkManager and the Worker class: I know its kind of a different question from the original, but how can I call the function from the fragment to the Worker class? cant find any solution for this.